# How to upload multiple image in laravel php

Tags: php, html, laravel

i am trying to upload multiple images in laravel, but it seems only one image in inserted into the database and i was wondering how can i be uploading all images not just one.

here is my controller

```
public function addProperty(Request $request){
        $data = $request->all();
        $pModel = new PropertyModel();
        
        return response()->json(["type"=>$pModel->addProperty($data,$request)]);
    }
```

here is my view

```
<h3>Gallery</h3>
        <div class="submit-section">
            <div id="selected-files"></div>
            <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple  onchange="Property.onImageUploadChange(event)" id="files" >
        </div>
```

here is my model

```
  public function addProperty($propertyData,$request){
        $db  = new Database;
        @session_start();
        $user = $_SESSION["user"];
        $propertyData["user_id"] = $user->user_id;
        unset($propertyData["_token"]);
        
        unset($propertyData["property_files"]);
        $res = $db->query($db->buildQuery($propertyData, $this->tableName)) or die(false);
        $lastID= $db->lastInsertID($res);
        $image = $request->file("property_files");
        $image->move(public_path('images'),$lastID.".jpg");
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: There are lots of tutorials on how to perform image/file uploads such as [this one](https://codingdriver.com/laravel-8-upload-multiple-images-example-tutorial.html).

Comment: yes i have watched them but am facing a problem where the images are not being uploaded to my images folder.

Comment: Perhaps you should look at them again and work out where you’re going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

may this code help you!
I'm work on backend and use this function:

```
public static function upload_image($image, $image_folder)
{
$image_new_name = time() . '_' . $image->getClientOriginalName();
$image_path = public_path('uploads\\' . $image_folder);
$image->move($image_path, $image_new_name);

return $image_folder . '/' . $image_new_name;
}
```

you can create a `SettingController` and put it there, then in your controller receive array of images and with `foreach` loop save them in your server like:

```
foreach($request->arrayImages as $image) {
     SettingController::upload_image($image, 'your folder name');
}
```